# For the Pynput module in python 3, key is not defined

Tags: python, pynput

This is my code.

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller #Allows input to the game
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
mouse = Controller()
keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.press(Key.escape)
keyboard.release(Key.escape)
```

Why is "Key" not defined when all the sites I've looked at specifically say to use it without adding in anything else?

Sites:

https://pypi.org/project/pynput/

https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to import it first, as the example in the first link you provided showed:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key
```